# How to get azure media service Deivery Url and Token for a asset at client side( SWT authentication)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-5.0, azure-media-services

I have uploaded the video into the Azure media service, associating the  ContentKeyType.EnvelopeEncryption with the asset. But how can I retrieve the Delivery Key for authentication, Delivery Url and and using these to how to authenticate the the user and play the video at client?

Answer (score 0):

IContenKey interface exposes GetKeyDeliveryUrl method. Here example of usage

```
Uri keyDeliveryServiceUri = contentKey.GetKeyDeliveryUrl(ContentKeyDeliveryType.BaselineHttp);
```

Full example of test which uses SWT token authentication can be found in [azure media service github repo.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/test/net/Scenario/DynamicEncryption/GetKeyDeliveryUrlTests.cs). See test name GetHlsKeyDeliveryUrlAndFetchKeyWithSWTAuthentication.

I would recommend to use JWT token type. Azure ACS will be retired soon and most identity providers including Azure Active directory have support for JWT token.